# How to make a informative textbox inside html page

Tags: html, css, textbox

Folks,

I am having a doubt. I wish to make a website. I am stuck at one concept.
Suppose my web page look like the below image.

[image]

Now, my doubt is how to make a `textbox` with blue color such that if anyone clicks on the tabs (like Home, About Us etc) on the background green web page, that p'cular content should appear in the blue box which is above the green box.
Should `css` should be used here ? Sample code ?

---

PS : Excuse me for this very image file (Done in MSPaint) and also if I am not able to present my question correctly.
Please feel free to modify my question in case you get my question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Give the tab that's active a class called .active which has the same green color as background-color?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up a JSfiddle showing how to do something like this with JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/Gj7qc/

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Gj7qc/1/

Comment: Almost correct. But I want some stuffs to be written when we click tab1. I don't want tab1 to be written on the blue web page. Any idea ?

Comment: What do you want to be written? Where is that value stored?

Comment: Suppose you click on "tab1" on green page, I want some paragraph's to appear in that blue box. Where should I write those para's ?